# After Deployment on IIS CSS' doesn't work properly

Tags: css, asp.net, iis

I have tried a lot of thing but I didn't accomplished when deploy on IIS my project it is not working properly such as modals besides It is working on localhost with these errors;

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> adminlte.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> bootstrap.bundle.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> jquery.dataTables.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> jquery.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> bootstrap.bundle.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> adminlte.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> bootstrap.bundle.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> jquery.dataTables.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
> dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js:5

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: thanks a lot @शेखर

Comment: Hi, Where is your all CSS files... ? I can't see any CSS file in your Solution Explorer.

Comment: It's not under the CSS folder it is on the another folder, also problem not only CSS' in addition js files doesn't load properly

Comment: I uploaded new screen shot of directory

Comment: Please check whether Static Content is added in the Windows Features (under Common HTTP Features).

Comment: How did you deploy the project to IIS?